Space Shuttle HUD use outside of landing?
Has the Space Shuttle's HUD ever been used for anything other than the entry, TAEM and landing phases, or has such usage ever been considered (e.g. as a visual reference for ISS proximity manoeuvres or satellite intercepts)?

There was a HUD calibration procedure, which required the crew to power up the HUD, that was done on orbit to fine-tune the HUD symbology positioning in preparation for landing day...

Why would they be looking out the front window during orbital maneuvers?

There was a procedure in the Malfunction book to align the Inertial Measurement Units (IMUs) using the Heads-up Display (HUD).
Procedure GNC FRP-2 IMU REFERENCE RECOVERY sent the crew to GNC SSR-2 MATRIX (TORQUE) ALIGN USING HUD STAR DATA
The procedure consisted of powering up the HUD and maneuvering the orbiter to point at selected stars, taking "marks" by pushing the ATT REF (Attitude Reference) pushbutton when the star was centered in the HUD boresight (as depicted below).

After the marks were taken, the IMUs were aligned, then cleanup steps were performed.
I do not know if the procedure was ever actually performed, but I do not think it was. I recall seeing it done in training occasionally. IMU Aligns were performed in flight, but the star trackers were used. Alignment using the HUD would have only been done for star tracker failures.
References:

Malfunction Procedures / Generic / Rev G pp. 8-4, 8-10 (HUD align procedures)
Orbit Ops Checklist / Generic / Rev M p. 7-2 (Nominal align procedure)


Pardon my ignorance, but how does the IMU+HUD compensate for parallax… or does it require the user/pilot’s head and eyes be prepositioned first?

@Dai the projected images on HUDs and their gunsight ancestors use collimators (or other optics) to appear at a distance ahead of the display itself. Those images should then also parallax around the way those stars would
